# 'int' object is not callable when using the sum function on a list

Tags: python, list

```
coinCount = [2 for i in range(4)]
total = sum(coinCount)
```

This gives me

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't understand why because

```
print type(coinCount)
```

Gives me

```
type <'list'>
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You no doubt used the identifier `sum` previously in your code as a local variable name, and the last value you bound to it was an `int`.  So, in that code snippet, you're trying to call the `int`.  `print sum` just before you try calling it and you'll see, but code inspection will probably reveal it faster.

This kind of problem is why expert Pythonistas keep telling newbies over and over "don't use builtin names for your own variables!" even when it's apparently not hurting a specific code snippet: it's a horrible habit, and a bug just waiting to happen, if you use identifiers such as `sum`, `file`, `list`, etc, as your own variables or functions!-)

Comment: A frequently recommended alternative is to put an underscore postfix on identifiers that would otherwise collide with reserved words and builtin identifiers; i.e. `type_` or `sum_` or `from_` (if you're into using prepositions as identifiers).

Comment: @cdleary very sound advice. I prefer this over prefixing with an underscore.

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to add on to what Alex Martelli said by saying don't use sum as a variable name but if you're program is too long already or you're using idle and you don't want to start over you can do

```
sum2 = sum
del sum
```

to transfer the value of sum into sum2 (if necessary) and delete the variable sum (allowing you to continue working with the sum function)