# Erroneous example in official Python tutorial (Chapter 9.10)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I copied the following example from **Python 3.6.1 Documentation, Chapter 9.10** into Jupyter Notebook (Python version 3.6.1):

```
xvec = [10, 20, 30]

yvec = [7, 5, 3]

sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec))         # dot product
```

While the official documentation says that it would print **260**, I got the following error in Notebook:

```
----> 4 sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This is definitely not just a question on 'int object is not callable', but more on the palpable error in what is considered to be the gospel for Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['int' object is not callable when using the sum function on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460087/int-object-is-not-callable-when-using-the-sum-function-on-a-list)

Comment: works for me in a script

Comment: Yes. In fact, if I change the last line to:
`value = sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec)) # dot product`
`print(value)`it works inside jupyter notebook itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by mistake you have overwritten `zip()` or/and `sum()`, which leads that your current code will not work. You can restore their default functionalities using `del`, like this example:

```
>>> zip = [1]
>>> zip
[1]
>>> del zip
>>> zip
<function zip>
```

So, you can try :

```
>>> del zip
>>> del sum
>>> xvec = [10, 20, 30]
>>> yvec = [7, 5, 3]
>>> sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec))
```

And it will output:

```
260
```

Answer (score 2):

The code should work as long as you didn't overwrite `zip` or `sum`:

```
>>> xvec = [10, 20, 30]
>>> yvec = [7, 5, 3]
>>> sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec))
260
```

Make sure that you didn't overwrite them:

```
>>> sum = 0  # <--- overwrite
>>> sum(x*y for x,y in zip(xvec, yvec))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```